# cannot move out of `guess`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure Rust

Tags: rust, mutex

today I tried to write this MusicGuesser with GTK for fun and got this error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `guess`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:63:32
   |
15 |     let mut guess = Arc::new(get_guess());
   |         --------- captured outer variable
16 |
17 |     app.connect_activate(move |app| {
   |                          ---------- captured by this `Fn` closure
...
63 |         button.connect_clicked(move |_| {
   |                                ^^^^^^^^ move out of `guess` occurs here
64 |             let mut guess = Arc::clone(&guess);
   |                                         -----
   |                                         |
   |                                         variable moved due to use in closure
   |                                         move occurs because `guess` has type `Arc<Vec<std::string::String>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I found some same questions about this error, but I didn't understand them. There is source code: https://pastebin.com/1pNxEiB5

Comment: Please post the source code instead of linking it. Links aren't considered permanent in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let guess = Arc::new(get_guess());
let cloned_guess = Arc::clone(&guess);
// ...
app.connect_activate(move |app| {
    // ...
    button.connect_clicked(move |_| {
        let guess = cloned_guess;

// ...
```

If you use something in a `move ||` closure, you move it *into* that closure. That means in your case you move the entire outer `guess` object in.

So you need to clone first, and then only move the cloned object in.

You will hit the next problem soon, though, because the content of `Arc` is **always immutable**. In Rust, you can never have multiple mutable references to the same thing. So in order to modify your `guess`, you will have to create *interior mutability* via `Mutex` or similar.